# Copy some files from source directory A to directory B and some files to Directory C with non sequential order

Tags: bash, scripts, cp

I am looking for a script to copy files from a source directory to two destination directories with non sequential order.

For instance I want to copy some files from source directory `A/` to destination directory `B/` and copy the remaining files to destination directory `C/`. It would be desirable as well if the files in directory `A/` are equally divided between directory `B/` and directory `C/`.

I have something like this:

```bash
$ tree A/ B/ C/
A/
├── file0
├── file1
├── file2
├── file3
├── file4
├── file5
├── file6
├── file7
├── file8
└── file9
B/
C/
```

And I want it to be like this:

```bash
$ tree A/ B/ C/
A/
├── file0
├── file1
├── file2
├── file3
├── file4
├── file5
├── file6
├── file7
├── file8
└── file9
B/
├── file1
├── file3
├── file5
├── file7
└── file9
C/
├── file0
├── file2
├── file4
├── file6
└── file8
```

Comment: @Raffa I have one directory where files are coming.I need to copy some of these  files to directort B and some files to directory C to avoid duplication.

Comment: Still not clear ... Duplicate filenames can't co-exist in the same directory "A" ... So, this can not be your problem or you did not describe the problem correctly ... [edit] your question to describe the problem and how it might happen and show examples where possible please.

Comment: @Raffa actually I have to copy files from source folders to two different folders but not in consecutive  order. Some files to folder b and some file to folder c hope I make it clear

Comment: Still not clear :-) ... I have added an answer below ... please look at it and try it ... It will ether solve your problem or it will help you to explain your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will copy one file to `B/` and the next file to `C/` and repeats until all files in `A/` are copied:

```bash
for f in A/*; do
i=$((i+1))
o=$((i%2))
[[ "$o" -eq 0 ]] && cp -v -- "$f" B/ || cp -v -- "$f" C/
done
```

This is a demonstration:

```bash
ubuntu@Lenovo:~/test$ mkdir A B C
ubuntu@Lenovo:~/test$ touch A/file{0..9}
ubuntu@Lenovo:~/test$ tree A/ B/ C/
A/
├── file0
├── file1
├── file2
├── file3
├── file4
├── file5
├── file6
├── file7
├── file8
└── file9
B/
C/

0 directories, 0 files
ubuntu@Lenovo:~/test$ for f in A/*; do
i=$((i+1))
o=$((i%2))
[[ "$o" -eq 0 ]] && cp -v -- "$f" B/ || cp -v -- "$f" C/
done
'A/file0' -> 'C/file0'
'A/file1' -> 'B/file1'
'A/file2' -> 'C/file2'
'A/file3' -> 'B/file3'
'A/file4' -> 'C/file4'
'A/file5' -> 'B/file5'
'A/file6' -> 'C/file6'
'A/file7' -> 'B/file7'
'A/file8' -> 'C/file8'
'A/file9' -> 'B/file9'
ubuntu@Lenovo:~/test$ tree A/ B/ C/
A/
├── file0
├── file1
├── file2
├── file3
├── file4
├── file5
├── file6
├── file7
├── file8
└── file9
B/
├── file1
├── file3
├── file5
├── file7
└── file9
C/
├── file0
├── file2
├── file4
├── file6
└── file8

0 directories, 5 files
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply Yes thats right this is what i want.. But please tell me what if i copy files from one server directory A  to multiple servers with same directory structure the way you  mentioned directory structure A B and C directories

I have already setup RSA public key for integration between servers for no password require only thanks in advance

Comment: @sunman For copying to directories on other servers, you can use `scp` instead of `cp` … please see an example here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/106482

Comment: dear like you propose me the answer above with same scanario but instead of folder i need to copy to servers. i have emailed you plz check

Comment: @sunman Please, ask a new question and include the bash code from this answer and state that you want to do the same but, copy from directory `A/` on the local machine to directories `B/` and `C/` that are located on other servers ... Please also include if the servers are on the same LAN with any other helpful information ... Meanwhile, please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/556770) the answer above so that I can fix this question and make it clearer and more useful to other users ... Then I will check your new question and try to help :-)